# How to automate the building of multiple versions of an Android app

Tags: android, node.js, ant

I have to build multiple apps with some minor differences in the code. The app code will be edited with data stored in an external .csv file. 
The apps have to be built with Ant and signed. This chain have to run on Windows, I would use Node.js.

I found [this doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline-ant.html) from Google Developers on how to build from command line. 
I tried to run the build and signing commands with Node.js, but I'm facing problems because they have prompts and inputs.

Do you have any suggestions on how to run this automation of building and signing?